# What does the level curve xy = 3 to the graph xy = z look like?

Tags: graphing-functions

I got this example from MIT courseware class on multivariable calculus  it was an example during the lecture. Just having difficulty with the visual.

Looking for the level curve xy = 3 to the graph xy= z.

Comment: ?A hyperbola is not a line.

Comment: Have you ever examined a map which indicates elevation by the use of contour lines? Contour lines are another name for level curves. In the case of $z=xy$ the surface has a saddle point at $(0,0)$. If the positive $y$-axis is North and the positive $x$-axis is East then the terrain rises to the northeast and southwest and declines to the southeast and the northwest.

Comment: You can also use online 3D plotters such as Wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d+plot&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%223DPlot%22,+%223dplotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22x

Comment: The level curves aren't the sheets of paper. They’re the *intersections* of those sheets of paper with the surface.

Comment: amd clears for me ...i thought the level curves were the sheets of paper...i guess it was the word "curves" that was messing me up...I don't see why they don't just call it a level line....because its not a sheet that is solid and the line may or may not be curved depending on what the 3d object looks like.

Comment: ..i guess if they use he word line people will think they are straight ...guess best to leave them as is ....and a hard head like me is happy to learn it.

Comment: For $z=xy$, the level curves are $y=\frac{z}{x}$, where $z$ is constant, in particular, $z=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a plot of $z = x y$ (blue) and $z = 3$ (orange):

[image]

Your question is a bit awkward.  The plot of $x y = 3$ is really a hyperbola that lies in the two-dimensional $xy$ plane.  The plot of $z = x y$ is a three-dimensional surface in a three-dimensional $xyz$ space.

Comment: Nice! exactly what I needed and the level "curve " is really a curved line of intersection where a level sheet cutting the 3D object is intersecting ...I was confused but now this is OK